# How to use JQuery to auto reload div content every X seconds?

Tags: jquery, html

I have been doing a web page, and i encountered a problem on reloading div content.

I have done some research, and all of those examples what i found on has a something like "script.php" on .load(), which is not what i need... ([example](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/07/auto-load-refresh-every-10-seconds-with.html))

Is there any way to use .load() to load only specific div content again?

(btw, sry bad english etc... And i hope my explanation makes any sense)

---

Code:

```
   <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function update(){
                $('#div1').load("index.html #div1");
            }
            setInterval( 'update()', 1000 );
        </script>
    </head>
```

---

```
    <body>
            <div id="div1">
                    <script language="JavaScript">
                       <!--
                         date=Date()
                         document.write(date)
                       //-->
                    </script>
            </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your requirement is just to call some function for certain interval of time. Then simply use :

```
function update()
    $('#div1').load("index.php");
    //$('#div1').load("index.jsp");
});

$(function() {
    update(); //to run on page load
    setInterval(update,1000);
}
```

use server side code for date as below:

**PHP:**

```
<h1><?= date("Y/m/d h:m:s") ?></h1>
```

**JSP:**

```
<h1>
    <%  
       Date date = new Date();
       SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");
       out.print(ft.format(date));
    %>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, using code that C-link posted, and using php date() instead of javascript (i use date/time to see if auto-update is working) i get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your code in [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready) like,

```
$(function(){
   setInterval( 'update()', 1000 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
function update(){
    $('#div1').load("index.html #div1");
}
setInterval( update, 1000 );
```

Or this:

```
function update(){
    $('#div1').load("index.html #div1");
}
setInterval( function(){
   update();
}, 1000 );
```